# How to create custom keyboard extension with images on it in Objective-C?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, keyboard

I am having an app in which I want to create my own custom keyboard.

In this custom keyboard, I want to put images.

Users can access this keyboard from anywhere in the device.

I want it like this [Link](https://itunes.apple.com/ca/app/memeboard-rage-faces-memes/id802802119?mt=8).

I want to make a keyboard like this [image]

I have searched a lot on this and I know there are lots of tutorials but most of those are in swift and another are not with keyboard extension.

I want proper guidance or any link of tutorial for this.

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Thanks...

Comment: Did you make any progress on this?

Comment: @jugutier: Yes, you can put images in your own keyboard with collection view and pressing on that, copy the image on the pasteboard. You can then paste the image while sending in messages or wherever the image sending is supported.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

So I got my answer from the below link which is a very nice tutorial in objective C.

[Custom keyboard with extensions in objective c for ios8](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gczzfq6DuHo)

Now, like I needed, if anyone wants to add custom images in it, you can just copy the image to the clipboard and paste the image where its needed.

For copying the png files, use the below code.

```
UIPasteboard *pasteboard = [UIPasteboard generalPasteboard];
NSString *imageName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%ld",(long)sender.tag];
NSString *newPathName = [[NSBundle mainBundle]pathForResource:imageName ofType:@"png"];
NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:newPathName];
[pasteboard setData:data forPasteboardType:@"public.png"];
```

This public.png comes from http://www.escape.gr/manuals/qdrop/UTI.html

You can choose any extension type you want to.
The pasteboard type changes as per the image extensions.

**Important note**: For image sending, the Apps which gives an access to paste the image copied from clipboard, only from those apps images will be sent.

I did it with the above solutions. Hope it helps someone else also.

Thanks...

Answer (score 1):

This question is several years old now, but if anyone has the same needs today, I have created a Swift library that helps you create keyboard extensions that support characters, operations like backspace, newline etc. as well as images. It also has support for copying images to the pasteboard and saving them to the photo album.

If you need a library like this, feel free to check it our here:

https://github.com/danielsaidi/KeyboardKit