# How to use images in Keyboard Extension?

Tags: ios, objective-c

Kindly Someone Help me, I want to develop my custom keyboard in objective-c. I am not find a way to use images in keyboard extension.Basically I want to show images on Keyboard and after click on image I want to paste on board. Kindly please help me share a way and tutorial link of keyboard extension in objective C with images.

similar to this link: [How to create custom keyboard extension with images on it in Objective-C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29247628/how-to-create-custom-keyboard-extension-with-images-on-it-in-objective-c)

I need proper steps to how use image on extension keyboard and how to share this image

Comment: Please kindly read this: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask